# Printing special characters in Eclipse-PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using eclipse with pydev, and I need to print Spanish words such as 'Opción', '¡Hola!'. But it prints this message:

> SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfa'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems you have a file which has non `utf-8` characters (in Eclipse by default it'll use your system encoding, so, it's probably `cp1252` or `latin1`).

Ideally, make sure you make things `utf-8` by default (if you're using **LiClipse**, this should be automatic, but if you're on **Eclipse/PyDev**, go to the **preferences > general > workspace** and mark '**text file encoding**' as `utf-8`).

For existing files, open them and press `Alt+Enter` to open the properties and make sure it's also `utf-8`.

Also, you should add a header:

`#coding: utf-8`

in the files which have non-ascii chars.